# onclick with condition from none to apply

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem that I need help with
I put a simple exemple of my code from w3schools to make it more simple.
I have a tab gallary with 4 images, that you can click on an image so it will get viewed bigger under.
This thing is working with onclick function.
What I want is to make the onclick= none until a condition happened (if text is contains something in this exemple.
I made the image onclick = none and the condition to be true so the myFunction(this). In other word to make the image clickable to get viewed under, but this is not working.
Sorry for my bad explanation,check the code and you will get it fast.
I just want to be able to activate the clicking on the image when a condition is true.

```js
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}

var mytextvar= document.getElementById("mytext").textContent

if(mytextvar == "keyboard"){
  document.getElementById("mytext").onclick = "myFunction(this);"
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- The four columns -->
<p id="mytext">keyboard</p>


<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/201" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/202" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/204" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function showImage(sourceImg) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = sourceImg.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = sourceImg.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}


var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img-cls");

imgs.forEach((img) => {

  img.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    checkStatus(this);
  });

});


function doImgAction(source, type) {
  if (source.classList.contains(type)) {
    showImage(source);
  } else {
    alert("You don't have enough credits to perform this action!");
  }
}


function checkStatus(source) {
  var mytextvar = document.getElementById("mytext");
  var myText = mytextvar.textContent.toLowerCase();

  switch (myText) {

    case "sliver":
      {
        doImgAction(source, 'sliver');
        break;
      }
    case "gold":
      {
        doImgAction(source, 'gold');
        break;
      }
    case "diamond":
      {
        doImgAction(source, 'diamond');
        break;
      }
    default:
      {
        return;
      }

  }

}
```

Comment: I want to make an image unavailable to click until a condition is true.
An exemple:
Think about game ranks.
If you are silver you can choose picture number 1 but nothing more.
but if you are gold you can choose picture number 1 and 2
and if you are diamond, then you can choose picture 1, 2 and 3.
the <p> tag colud contain the word silver, gold or diamond.
If am on the gold rank then I won't be able to click on picture number 3, but I can click on picture number 1 or 2

Comment: Hi @saliemantoun please check the edited code. thanks

Comment: Thanks for helping, it works :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a conditional for **adding** an `onclick` event:

```
if(mytextvar == "keyboard"){
   document.getElementById("mytext").onclick = "myFunction(this);"
}
```

However, when the condition `mytextvar == "keyboard"` is true, the event will be added and then it would never be deactivated, because you never deactivate it in the code.

What you can do is to move the conditional *inside* the function, so js would check the conditional every time an image is clicked, and then the code would be executed or not depending on the condition

```
function myFunction(imgs) {

  var mytextvar= document.getElementById("mytext").textContent

  // If condition is false, return of the function
  if(mytextvar != "keyboard")
    return;

  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("mytext").onclick = "myFunction(this);"
```

Note: the event would always be executed, but you return early if the condition is false

Comment: Thank for helping, I will make it clear here.
I want to make an image unavailable to click until a condition is true.
An exemple:
Think about game ranks.
If you are silver you can choose picture number 1 but nothing more.
but if you are gold you can choose picture number 1 and 2
and if you are diamond, then you can choose picture 1, 2 and 3.
the <p> tag colud contain the word silver, gold or diamond.
If am on the gold rank then I won't be able to click on picture number 3, but I can click on picture number 1 or 2